# Dumping Windows 10

Tags: versions

I'm not very PC literate and am sick to death of Windows 10!

So I'm asking for a bit of advice.
I own a HPlaptop 14s-dq0xxx, Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 5405U, with 4GB RAM.

Is there a version of Ubuntu that someone with very limited knowledge of all things computer programming (that would be me) can install into the laptop and retain full functioning of screen, sound, wifi, and anything else you can think of)?

Or is it a case of taking it to a computer repair shop and asking a clever person to install Ubuntu for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Hazmat. You can download and test Ubuntu without installing it first running it from a pendrive. This way you can check that everything works fine first. Then there are some guides to install it along with windows too or completely replace windows. Keep in mind that you need to have a backup of all your data.

Comment: here is more information to start:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: Most  Windows programs will not run on Ubuntu/Linux.  There are many Ubuntu/Linux programs that will replace them and work just as well.  There are a very few programs that work only on Windows and no good replacements for them.  Most people are lucky and do not use them, but if you are one that needs a specific program, would google it first and see if a linux replacement is available.  With your computer specs would try Lubuntu or Xubuntu instead of default Ubuntu, they are lighter desktop systems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: You can download Ubuntu from ubuntu.com (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), write it to thumb-drive or other install media (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
) then try it before installing it (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)  Same applies to flavors of Ubuntu too (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, much appreciated.
I had done just as you suggested BUT had multiple problems which were system 'inspired'. 

As for Windows software? 
I just don't use it preferring open source i.e. OpenOffice.
Most other programs all have linux versions available.

Answer (score 0):

Installation and usage of Ubuntu is quite easy for even a beginner without any knowledge of computer programming if you are not needed to dig deeper into advanced options of installation. Infact, it's easier to install Ubuntu than Windows. You just download the ISO file, put it in pendrive using Rufus or other, boot using the same during startup and Ubuntu itself will guide you further. If you're ready to loose your old files, installation will become much easier since you don't have to mess with partitions.

Hope this helps. :)